# Как взять текст из lineEdit PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

Я только начал пользоваться библиотекой PyQt5 и у меня возник вопрос как взять текст из `lineEdit`.

Я делаю лаунчер майнкрафта и мне надо чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Играть" - текст из `lineEdit` приравниваля к переменной `NICKNAME`.

Мой код:

```
from lib2to3.pgen2.token import COMMA
from re import sub
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
import subprocess

#                                  settings
NICKNAME = "l_5_TREYKER_5_l"
COMMAND_1_16_5 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_java.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//Forge 1.16.5//natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//forge//1.16.5-36.2.29//forge-1.16.5-36.2.29.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//9.1//asm-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//9.1//asm-commons-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//9.1//asm-tree-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-util//9.1//asm-util-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-analysis//9.1//asm-analysis-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//cpw//mods//modlauncher//8.1.3//modlauncher-8.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//cpw//mods//grossjava9hacks//1.3.3//grossjava9hacks-1.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//accesstransformers//3.0.1//accesstransformers-3.0.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//antlr//antlr4-runtime//4.9.1//antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//eventbus//4.0.0//eventbus-4.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//forgespi//3.2.0//forgespi-3.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//coremods//4.0.6//coremods-4.0.6.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//unsafe//0.2.0//unsafe-0.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//electronwill//night-config//core//3.6.3//core-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//electronwill//night-config//toml//3.6.3//toml-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//jline//jline//3.12.1//jline-3.12.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//maven//maven-artifact//3.6.3//maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//jodah//typetools//0.8.3//typetools-0.8.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.15.0//log4j-api-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.15.0//log4j-core-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-slf4j18-impl//2.15.0//log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecrell//terminalconsoleappender//1.2.0//terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.4//jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//spongepowered//mixin//0.8.4//mixin-0.8.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//nashorn-core-compat//15.1.1.1//nashorn-core-compat-15.1.1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.3.9//patchy-1.3.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j//66.1//icu4j-66.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//javabridge//1.0.22//javabridge-1.0.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.25.Final//netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//brigadier//1.0.17//brigadier-1.0.17.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//datafixerupper//4.0.26//datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//2.0.28.12//authlib-2.0.28.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//8.2.1//fastutil-8.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//3.2.2//lwjgl-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-jemalloc//3.2.2//lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-openal//3.2.2//lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-opengl//3.2.2//lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-glfw//3.2.2//lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-stb//3.2.2//lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-tinyfd//3.2.2//lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.11.3//text2speech-1.11.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//Forge 1.16.5//Forge 1.16.5.jar" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-exports=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming --add-opens=java.base/java.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher --username '+NICKNAME+' --version Forge 1.16.5 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType modified --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget fmlclient --fml.forgeVersion 36.2.29 --fml.mcVersion 1.16.5 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20210115.111550'
COMMAND_1_14_2 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_java.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.14.2//natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.14.2//1.10//tl_skin_cape_1.14.2-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.3.9//patchy-1.3.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//javabridge//1.0.22//javabridge-1.0.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.25.Final//netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//brigadier//1.0.17//brigadier-1.0.17.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//datafixerupper//2.0.24//datafixerupper-2.0.24.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.6.251//authlib-1.6.251.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//8.2.1//fastutil-8.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.14.16//realms-1.14.16.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//3.2.1//lwjgl-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-jemalloc//3.2.1//lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-openal//3.2.1//lwjgl-openal-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-opengl//3.2.1//lwjgl-opengl-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-glfw//3.2.1//lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-stb//3.2.1//lwjgl-stb-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.11.3//text2speech-1.11.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.14.2//1.14.2.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.14.2 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.14 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --tweakClass org.tlauncher.tweaker.Tweaker'
COMMAND_1_12_2 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe -Djava.library.path=C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.12.2//natives -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.12.2//1.14//tl_skin_cape_1.12.2-1.14.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.2.3//patchy-1.2.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecjorbis//20101023//codecjorbis-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecwav//20101023//codecwav-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//libraryjavasound//20101123//libraryjavasound-20101123.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//librarylwjglopenal//20100824//librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//soundsystem//20120107//soundsystem-20120107.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.9.Final//netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.6.251//authlib-1.6.251.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.10.22//realms-1.10.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//7.1.0//fastutil-7.1.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl_util//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.10.3//text2speech-1.10.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.12.2//1.12.2.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch1_12_2 --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.12.2 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType release --width 925 --height 530'
COMMAND_1_8_9 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.8.9//natives" -cp C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.8.9//1.15//tl_skin_cape_1.8.9-1.15.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//netty//1.8.8//netty-1.8.8.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//3.4.0//jna-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//4.6//jopt-simple-4.6.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecjorbis//20101023//codecjorbis-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecwav//20101023//codecwav-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//libraryjavasound//20101123//libraryjavasound-20101123.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//librarylwjglopenal//20100824//librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//soundsystem//20120107//soundsystem-20120107.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.0.23.Final//netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//17.0//guava-17.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.3.2//commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.4//commons-io-2.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.9//commons-codec-1.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.2.4//gson-2.2.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.7.211//authlib-1.7.211.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.7.59//realms-1.7.59.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.0-beta9//log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.0-beta9//log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl_util//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//tv//twitch//twitch//6.5//twitch-6.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.8.9//1.8.9.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch1_8_9 --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.8.9 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userProperties {} --userType mojang --width 925 --height 530'


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 380, 121, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 430, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 410, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 410, 300, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 400, 200, 13))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
     
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        global NICKNAME
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Играть"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Выберете версию"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Forge 1.16.5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1.14.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "1.12.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "1.8.9"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "текущий ник: "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", NICKNAME))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "смена ника в разработке"))

ver = "choise version"


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.current_text_changed)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.playbtnevent)

        global NICKNAME

    def current_text_changed(self, text):
        global ver
        ver = text

    def playbtnevent(self):
        ## incorrect version
        if ver == "Выберете версию":
            print("[versions] incorected version")
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка", "Пожалуйста выберете версию", QMessageBox.Ok) 
        if ver == "choise version":
            print("[versions] incorected version")
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка", "Пожалуйста выберете версию", QMessageBox.Ok) 
            #1.16.5
        if ver == "Forge 1.16.5":
            print("[versions] started minecraft Forge 1.16.5 ")
            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_16_5)
            print("mc is stopped")
        if ver == "1.14.2":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.14.2 ")
            subprocess.Popen(COMMAND_1_14_2)
            print("mc is stopped")
        if ver == "1.12.2":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.12.2 ")
            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_12_2)
            print("mc is stopped")
        if ver == "1.8.9":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.8.9 ")
            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_8_9)
            print("mc is stopped")

    def printtext(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                                     
    w.show()                                                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Не рекомендуется злоупотреблять глобальными переменными,
почитайте [**Почему глобальные переменные - зло?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) 
Вам просто надо сделать эти объекты атрибутами класса и все. 
Смотрите, например на объект `self.NICKNAME`

Я не знаю что вы собираетесь запускать в `subprocess`, поэтому закомментировал !!!
Тут у вас могут быть проблемы.

То, что вы спрашиваете, отмечено **`# +++ !!!`**

```
# ??? from lib2to3.pgen2.token import COMMA
# ??? from re import sub

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox

# ??? import subprocess


'''
#  settings    Я не знаю что это, поэтому закомментировал   !!!!!!!!!
NICKNAME = "l_5_TREYKER_5_l"
COMMAND_1_16_5 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_java.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//Forge 1.16.5//natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//forge//1.16.5-36.2.29//forge-1.16.5-36.2.29.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//9.1//asm-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//9.1//asm-commons-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//9.1//asm-tree-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-util//9.1//asm-util-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-analysis//9.1//asm-analysis-9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//cpw//mods//modlauncher//8.1.3//modlauncher-8.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//cpw//mods//grossjava9hacks//1.3.3//grossjava9hacks-1.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//accesstransformers//3.0.1//accesstransformers-3.0.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//antlr//antlr4-runtime//4.9.1//antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//eventbus//4.0.0//eventbus-4.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//forgespi//3.2.0//forgespi-3.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//coremods//4.0.6//coremods-4.0.6.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//unsafe//0.2.0//unsafe-0.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//electronwill//night-config//core//3.6.3//core-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//electronwill//night-config//toml//3.6.3//toml-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//jline//jline//3.12.1//jline-3.12.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//maven//maven-artifact//3.6.3//maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//jodah//typetools//0.8.3//typetools-0.8.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.15.0//log4j-api-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.15.0//log4j-core-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-slf4j18-impl//2.15.0//log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.15.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecrell//terminalconsoleappender//1.2.0//terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.4//jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//spongepowered//mixin//0.8.4//mixin-0.8.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraftforge//nashorn-core-compat//15.1.1.1//nashorn-core-compat-15.1.1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.3.9//patchy-1.3.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j//66.1//icu4j-66.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//javabridge//1.0.22//javabridge-1.0.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.25.Final//netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//brigadier//1.0.17//brigadier-1.0.17.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//datafixerupper//4.0.26//datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//2.0.28.12//authlib-2.0.28.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//8.2.1//fastutil-8.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//3.2.2//lwjgl-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-jemalloc//3.2.2//lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-openal//3.2.2//lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-opengl//3.2.2//lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-glfw//3.2.2//lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-stb//3.2.2//lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-tinyfd//3.2.2//lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.11.3//text2speech-1.11.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//Forge 1.16.5//Forge 1.16.5.jar" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-exports=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming --add-opens=java.base/java.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher --username '+NICKNAME+' --version Forge 1.16.5 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType modified --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget fmlclient --fml.forgeVersion 36.2.29 --fml.mcVersion 1.16.5 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20210115.111550'
COMMAND_1_14_2 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_java.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.14.2//natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.14.2//1.10//tl_skin_cape_1.14.2-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.3.9//patchy-1.3.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//javabridge//1.0.22//javabridge-1.0.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.25.Final//netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//brigadier//1.0.17//brigadier-1.0.17.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//datafixerupper//2.0.24//datafixerupper-2.0.24.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.6.251//authlib-1.6.251.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//8.2.1//fastutil-8.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.14.16//realms-1.14.16.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//3.2.1//lwjgl-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-jemalloc//3.2.1//lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-openal//3.2.1//lwjgl-openal-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-opengl//3.2.1//lwjgl-opengl-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-glfw//3.2.1//lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl-stb//3.2.1//lwjgl-stb-3.2.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.11.3//text2speech-1.11.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.14.2//1.14.2.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.14.2 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.14 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --tweakClass org.tlauncher.tweaker.Tweaker'
COMMAND_1_12_2 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe -Djava.library.path=C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.12.2//natives -cp "C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.12.2//1.14//tl_skin_cape_1.12.2-1.14.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//patchy//1.2.3//patchy-1.2.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//4.4.0//jna-4.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//5.0.3//jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecjorbis//20101023//codecjorbis-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecwav//20101023//codecwav-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//libraryjavasound//20101123//libraryjavasound-20101123.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//librarylwjglopenal//20100824//librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//soundsystem//20120107//soundsystem-20120107.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.1.9.Final//netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//21.0//guava-21.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.5//commons-lang3-3.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.5//commons-io-2.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.10//commons-codec-1.10.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.8.0//gson-2.8.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.6.251//authlib-1.6.251.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.10.22//realms-1.10.22.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//it//unimi//dsi//fastutil//7.1.0//fastutil-7.1.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.8.1//log4j-api-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.8.1//log4j-core-2.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl_util//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//text2speech//1.10.3//text2speech-1.10.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.12.2//1.12.2.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch1_12_2 --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.12.2 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userType mojang --versionType release --width 925 --height 530'
COMMAND_1_8_9 = '"C://Programs//.minecraft//runtime//jre-legacy//windows//jre-legacy//bin//java.exe" -Djava.library.path="C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.8.9//natives" -cp C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//tl_skin_cape_1.8.9//1.15//tl_skin_cape_1.8.9-1.15.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-tree//6.2//asm-tree-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm//6.2//asm-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//ow2//asm//asm-commons//6.2//asm-commons-6.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//minecraft//launchwrapper//1.12//launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//netty//1.8.8//netty-1.8.8.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//oshi-project//oshi-core//1.1//oshi-core-1.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//jna//3.4.0//jna-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//dev//jna//platform//3.4.0//platform-3.4.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//ibm//icu//icu4j-core-mojang//51.2//icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//sf//jopt-simple//jopt-simple//4.6//jopt-simple-4.6.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecjorbis//20101023//codecjorbis-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//codecwav//20101023//codecwav-20101023.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//libraryjavasound//20101123//libraryjavasound-20101123.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//librarylwjglopenal//20100824//librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//paulscode//soundsystem//20120107//soundsystem-20120107.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//io//netty//netty-all//4.0.23.Final//netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//guava//guava//17.0//guava-17.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-lang3//3.3.2//commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-io//commons-io//2.4//commons-io-2.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-codec//commons-codec//1.9//commons-codec-1.9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jinput//jinput//2.0.5//jinput-2.0.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//net//java//jutils//jutils//1.0.0//jutils-1.0.0.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//google//code//gson//gson//2.2.4//gson-2.2.4.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//tlauncher//authlib//1.7.211//authlib-1.7.211.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//com//mojang//realms//1.7.59//realms-1.7.59.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//commons//commons-compress//1.8.1//commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpclient//4.3.3//httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//commons-logging//commons-logging//1.1.3//commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//httpcomponents//httpcore//4.3.2//httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-api//2.0-beta9//log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//apache//logging//log4j//log4j-core//2.0-beta9//log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//org//lwjgl//lwjgl//lwjgl_util//2.9.4-nightly-20150209//lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//libraries//tv//twitch//twitch//6.5//twitch-6.5.jar";"C://Programs//.minecraft//versions//1.8.9//1.8.9.jar" -Xmn128M -Xmx6636M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C://Programs//.minecraft org.tlauncher.Launch1_8_9 --username '+NICKNAME+' --version 1.8.9 --gameDir C://Programs//.minecraft --assetsDir C://Programs//.minecraft//assets --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid 8e9c15fb9b1e41a39c1b16aed457763b --accessToken null --userProperties {} --userType mojang --width 925 --height 530'
'''

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(639, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 380, 121, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 430, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 410, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 410, 300, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 400, 200, 13))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
# ???        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
# ???        global NICKNAME
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Играть"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Выберете версию"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Forge 1.16.5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1.14.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "1.12.2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "1.8.9"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "текущий ник: "))
# ???        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", NICKNAME))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "смена ника в разработке"))

# ??? ver = "choise version"


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.NICKNAME = "l_5_TREYKER_5_l"                                       # +++
        self.ver = "choise version"                                             # +++
        self.label_3.setText(self.NICKNAME)                                     # +++
    
        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.current_text_changed)
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(121, 71)                                   # +++
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.playbtnevent)
        
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)                    # +++ !!!

#        global NICKNAME
    def text_changed(self, text):                                               # +++ !!!
        self.NICKNAME = text                                                    # +++ !!!

    def current_text_changed(self, text):
#        global ver
#        ver = text
        self.ver = text                                                         # +++

    def playbtnevent(self):
        print(f"\n[versions] {self.ver}")
    
        if self.ver == "Выберете версию" or self.ver == "choise version":
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка", "Пожалуйста выберете версию", QMessageBox.Ok) 
            return
            
        if self.lineEdit.text():                                                # +++ !!!
            self.label_3.setText(self.NICKNAME)                                 # +++ !!!
            

        if self.ver == "Forge 1.16.5":
            print("[versions] started minecraft Forge 1.16.5 ")
# ???            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_16_5)
            print("mc is stopped")
        elif self.ver == "1.14.2":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.14.2 ")
# ???            subprocess.Popen(COMMAND_1_14_2)
            print("mc is stopped")
        elif self.ver == "1.12.2":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.12.2 ")
# ???            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_12_2)
            print("mc is stopped")
        elif self.ver == "1.8.9":
            print("[versions] started minecraft 1.8.9 ")
# ???            subprocess.call(COMMAND_1_8_9)
            print("mc is stopped")

# ???   vvvvvvvvv ???
    def printtext(self, text):
        print(f'????????????????????????  {text}')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                                     
    w.show()                                                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]